# Spell Correction with Python (pyspellchecker)

Tags: python, nlp, spell-checking

I wanna build a spell correction using python and I try to use pyspellchecker, because I have to build my own dictionary and I think pyspellchecker is easy to use with our own model or dictionary. My problem is, how to load and return my word with case_sensitive is On?
I have tried this:

`spell = SpellChecker(language=None, case_sensitive=True)`

but when I load my file contains many text like 'Hello' with this code:

`spell.word_frequency.load_text_file('myfile.txt')`

and when I start to spell with `spell.correction('Hello')` its return `'hello'` (lower case).
Do you know how to build our own model or dictionary with our letters not diminished or it stays uppercase?

Or if you have a recommendation for spell-checking with our own model please let me know, Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```py
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

spell = SpellChecker(language=None, case_sensitive=True)
a = spell.word_frequency.load_words(["Hello", "HELLO", "I", "AM", "Alok", "Mishra"])

# find those words that may be misspelled
misspelled = spell.unknown(["helo", "Alk", "Mishr"])

for word in misspelled:
    # Get the one `most likely` answer
    print(spell.correction(word))

    # Get a list of `likely` options
    print(spell.candidates(word))
```

Output:

```
Alok
{'Alok'}
Hello
{'Hello'}
Mishra
{'Mishra'}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your solution. It worked! But, if we are going to save our model and then load our model that has been saved before, I got my word being lowercase automatically by pyspellchecker.

I export my model using `spell.export('my_custom_dictionary.gz', gzipped=True)`

and load my model using `spell.word_frequency.load_text_file('./path-to-my-model.gz')`